# how to disable php warning mk.dir()

Tags: php

it is about this script:
When uploading a file, first check whether the directory "uploads" exists, if not: create the directory.
When the directory already exists and uploading a file, there comes a warning:

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in....

How to disable this warning?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

// array with allowed extensions
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "zip", "html", "htm", "js", "css",      "less", "txt", "php");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

// create map "uploads" if doesn't exists
$root = '/uploads/';
    if (!is_dir($root)) {
        mkdir("uploads/", 0777);
                    echo 'The map uploads is created!'; 



if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/html")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/javascript")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/css")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/less")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) // 2 Mb max
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
// echo's if upload is succeeded
echo 'Status: upload succesvol!<br />';
echo 'Bestand: ' . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . '<br />';
echo 'Type: ' . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . '<br />';
echo 'Grootte: ' . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . ' kB<br />';

  $newfilename = uniqid().".".end(explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]));
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $newfilename);
  // het pad naar het bestand dat geupload is; ervan uitgaande dat de map uploads in de  root staat
  echo 'Url: ' . '<b>http://www.jouwwebsite.nl/uploads/' . $newfilename.'</b>';
  echo '<br /><br />';
 }

  else
 {
 // echo if file extension is not allowed
 echo "Niet toegestaan bestand";
 }
 }
 else {

 }

 }
 } // end request_method POST 
?>
```

Comment: Code around it. Check first if the file already exists in there, if it does, either rename the file you're moving, or delete the existing one. You shouldn't suppress errors, you should code for them - make your application flexible!

Comment: That's not 2MB. That's 19.073486328125MB

Comment: Use a custom error handling and put a `try catch` statement.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a @ symbol in front of any function to suppress its error messages, warnings or notices.

```
@mkdir('/path/to/dir');
```

However, it is much better if you put an if statement so that you use that function only when you need it.

Comment: Worst. Suggestion. Ever. People do this too often already and then have the audacity to post on SO that their code doesn't work and there are no errors!

Comment: I agree with you that lots of new programmers often find hard time because they can't see error messages. However, suppressing error messages is perfectly fine if you know what you're doing. Also, don't forget that production servers usually have errors suppressed anyway through php.ini settings.

Comment: They do indeed, which is exactly why people shouldn't be suppressing any errors on a development box. Unless they are developing code on a production server, of course, in which case they deserve all the pain they get.

Answer (score 1):

Use `file_exists($root)` instead of `is_dir` in `if` condition.

```
if(!file_exists($root))
  mkdir("uploads/", 0777);
```

Comment: i also tried that but same result, the warning keeps coming

Comment: Use @ operator like this @mkdir("uploads/", 0777); this will hide the warning message. What is your exact needs?

Comment: the @ sign works perfect, however, i thought it could be fixed with making the right loop for it, and that was my question actually: how to make this loop so that the error does not appear

Comment: Use this `$root = "uploads/"`

Answer (score 1):

$root = '/uploads/'; is an absolute path, and the following condition is probably returning false every time. Then it tries to create a "uploads" folder using a relative path, which was already created on a previous run of your script, thus the error.